# Create-react-app won't provide template despite react being up to date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've tried to create a new react directory with `npx create-react-app` and with every solution I've tried, the template was not provided with the recommended reasoning being that I might be using an outdated version of `create-react-app`.

I've checked what version of React is being downloaded and it up to date (18.2.0).

I've cleared the cache in my directory, uninstalled `create-react-app` globally multiple times, checked in my '~/users/name' directory to manually delete it. I installed with both `npx create-react-app@latest` and without `@latest`.

```
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint@8.56.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-watch-typeahead@1.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@eslint/eslintrc@2.1.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@eslint/js@8.56.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-scope@7.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-visitor-keys@3.4.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'espree@9.6.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/parser@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-plugin-testing-library@5.11.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0', npm: '>=6' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/scope-manager@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/type-utils@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'typescript@5.3.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/types@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@5.62.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'sucrase@3.35.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16 || 14 >=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'glob@10.3.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16 || 14 >=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'minimatch@9.0.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16 || 14 >=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'minipass@7.0.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16 || 14 >=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'path-scurry@1.10.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16 || 14 >=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.15.5', npm: '8.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1484 packages, and audited 1485 packages in 2m

250 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
```

partial package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error listed above, if you are using NodeJS v14 then it needs to be `v14.17` or higher but you are using `v14.15.5`.

Since this is an old version of Node, I recommend you upgrade.  Consider going to the newest version of v18.  I also recommend that you use Node Version Manager (`nvm`) for managing the versions of Node installed on your development machine and for switching between versions of Node.  You could simply do `nvm install v18` and then `nvm use v18`.

Also note that `create-react-app` is [no longer being actively maintained](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487#issuecomment-1409720741).  React recommends that you move to a different build/development system such as `Vite`.  Since you are creating a new project, now is the time to adopt a new build system.  Personally, I have moved to using Vite for all my React projects.

Comment: `Consider going to the newest version of v18` ... isn't v20 the latest LTS version?

Comment: Yes, but it is "bleeding edge"  LTS.  :)  I have run into a lot of existing libraries that have full support for v18 but v20 support is "still coming".  Since this individual is struggling with v14, I figured we should get them to "newest-with-least-chance-of-issues"  :)

Comment: I did not realise that - noted.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a simple thing, I forgot to check if I needed to upgrade NodeJS.

Comment: Read the error message.  Understand it.  Error messages are a developers Best Friend!  :)  If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted so that the question is considered complete.